# How to reuse my logic as a function in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a logic on input focus and I'm passing few values with logic. Now I want to reuse this logic in too many input focus. How can I do that?

My logic code:

```
<input
    type="text"
    onFocus={(e) =>
        data?
            move_box_click(
                data.One.name.split(",")[0] * docWidth,
                data.One.name.split(",")[1] * docHeight,
                data.One.name.split(",")[3] * docHeight - data.One.name.split(",")[1] * docHeight + 2,
                data.One.name.split(",")[2] * docWidth - data.One.name.split(",")[0] * docWidth + 2,
                e
            ) : ""
    }
/>

<input
    type="text"
    onFocus={(e) =>
        data?
            move_box_click(
                data.Two.name.split(",")[0] * docWidth,
                data.Two.name.split(",")[1] * docHeight,
                data.Two.name.split(",")[3] * docHeight - data.Two.name.split(",")[1] * docHeight + 2,
                data.Two.name.split(",")[2] * docWidth - data.Two.name.split(",")[0] * docWidth + 2,
                e
            ) : ""
    }
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function and pass the reference to the `onFocus` attribute, like this:

```
const myFocusHandler = (e, name) =>
data?
move_box_click(
name.split(",")[0] * docWidth,
name.split(",")[1] * docHeight,
name.split(",")[3] * docHeight - name.split(",")[1] * docHeight + 2,
name.split(",")[2] * docWidth - name.split(",")[0] * docWidth + 2,
e
) : ""

<input type="text" onFocus={(e) => myFocusHandler(e, data.One.name)} />
<input type="text" onFocus={(e) => myFocusHandler(e, data.Two.name)} />
```

Comment: but there is difference between two input focus in my question "data.One.name" this is for first & "data.Two.name" this is for second. how to pass this?

Comment: Oh! Then the method is not the same.
In this case, maybe you can pass the value `name` to the function:
```
const myFocusHandler = (name) => {/*your logic with name...*/}
<input type="text" onFocus={(e) => myFocusHandler(data.One.name)} />
<input type="text" onFocus={(e) => myFocusHandler(data.Two.name)} />
```

Comment: but i also need to pass (e) with (name).

Comment: I updated my response, please check it

Comment: Thanks @Denilson Anachury this is working fine now...